# Python findall and regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am parsing an xml file (called xml below) that has lines of two varying types:

```
1. <line a="a1" b="b1" c="c1">
2. <line a="a2" c="c2">
```

I am trying to pull a2 and c2 only from the second type, however this regular expression also captures the first type:

```
>>> list = re.findall('<line a="(.*)" c="(.*)">', xml)
>>> print(list)
[('a1" b="b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'c2')]
```

How would I capture just the second type?

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse XML to begin with? They are not exactly regular... Have you look into the [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library, for instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The * operator is greedy by default. Try ([^"]*) instead of (.*)

Answer (score 8):

This makes much more sense with a proper XML parsing library like [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), instead of resorting to regex. For instance:

```
>>> xmlstr = """\
... <root>
...   <line a="a1" b="b1" c="c1"></line>
...   <line a="a2" c="c2"></line>
... </root>
... """
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.XML(xmlstr)
>>> root.findall('./line')
[<Element 'line' at 0x226db70>, <Element 'line' at 0x226de48>]
>>> filtered = [line for line in root.findall('./line') if line.get('b') is None]
>>> for line in filtered:
...     print ET.tostring(line)
...
<line a="a2" c="c2" />

>>>
```

Comment: I ran it through timeit and the regular expression solution is about 50 times faster. So if speed is important, you know what you are looking for and you know what kind of xml you get then going the regex way might be the better option

Comment: At the cost of maintainability and readability. There is also `cElementTree` that implements the same API, but in native C as extension module. But if speed is all that important to you, why use Python in the first place? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for providing this method as well. It will be useful for some other tasks I'm working on.